# Redirect stdout to file with nohup doesn't work

Tags: background-process, stdout, nohup, stderr

I'm trying to run a C-program in the background. I also want to save the stdout-outputs of the program.

But if I try the following, nohup only redirects stderr-outputs to the logfile.txt:

```
nohup ./GetTempValues 11 4 > logfile.txt 2>&1 &
```

Whereby 11 and 4 are the parameters I need to pass to my program and the last `&` is for running the program in the background (GetTempValues is my program).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Guido points out above, **nohup** already redirects standard error for you unless you redirect it to a file.  If you're using Linux, it can be instructive to run a simple command under nohup and look at the calls to `dup2(2)` immediately before `execve(2)`.

I doubt you're seeing what you think you're seeing.  Let's think about what happens when you say

```
nohup foo 2>&1
```

1. The shell redirects stderr to stdout.
2. It then invokes **nohup**, which inherits that situation (stderr and stdout using the same file descriptor).
3. **nohup** opens `nohup.out` (file descriptor 3), dups it to file descriptor 1, and closes 3.
4. **nohup** notices stderr is not file, and dups file descriptor 1 to 2, too.  Thus file descriptors 1 and 2 both refer to `nohup.out`.
5. **nohup** calls `exec` with any arguments provided on the command line (in this case, *foo*).  The new process inherits the file descriptors that **nohup** set up for it.

From the command line you cannot create a case in which, as you say, *nohup only redirects stderr-outputs*.  **nohup** always writes stdout and stderr to a file.  stdout goes either to one you specify via redirection, or to `nohup.out`; stderr follows stdout unless you explicitly redirect it to another file.

The one peculiar aspect of using `2>&1` with **nohup** is that GNU's version produces a pointless message on stderr, *nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’*.  (What other utility writes a message to standard error that amounts to saying, *acting per documentation on instructions*?)  Normally that noise is written to the terminal; under redirection it winds up as the first line of the output file.

Answer (score 11):

Are you sure that `GetTempValues` produces any standard output to begin with? Because your syntax "works for me":

```
$ nohup perl test.pl >logfile.txt 2>&1 &
[1] 20964
$ cat logfile.txt 
this goes to stderr
this goes to stdout
[1]+  Done                    nohup perl test.pl > logfile.txt 2>&1
```

where `test.pl` is

```
print STDOUT "this goes to stdout\n";
print STDERR "this goes to stderr\n";
```

PS: Redirecting STDERR to STDOUT with `2>&1` is not necessary with `nohup` in your example, because *"if standard error is a terminal, it is directed to the same place as the standard output."* (`nohup` man page).